# jquery json doesn't return any value /repsonse

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using the getJSON to get the json value to be returned by a page,
but there is no response from the function..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert ("dfdfad");
        function sam()
        {
            alert("entere");
            $.getJSON(
                'https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?',
                {
                    'auth-userid':'234343',
                    'auth-password':'xxxxxxxx',
                    'domain-name':'yyyyy',
                    'tlds':'com',
                    'tlds':'info',
                    'suggest-alternative':'true'
                },
                function(json,textStatus,xhr) {
                    alert ("inside the fun");
                    alert("JSON Data: " + json);
                }
            );
            alert("finish");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
</div>
<button onclick=sam();>Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**When i used the following url from the browser it returns the value exactly as json..**

*The following url may not work from other ip because it needs a registration of ip to get response.. I'm sure that my ip is registered and its working*

```
https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=2343432&auth-password=xxxxxx&domain-name=testhiox&tlds=com&tlds=info&tlds=org&suggest-alternative=true
```

what may be the issue?

Comment: I would mask my password if I were you, just put xxx

Comment: That's a test environment and also the username and password would expire after some time.. That's why i didn't mask them

Comment: Are you sure you're not bumping into cross domain restrictions or anything like that? (I don't see you using jsonp there)

Comment: Also why is password inside JS files. I mean if it's something that is fetched from an input supplied by user then might be OK, but a username/password pair should never be inside a JS file because anyone can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check what the HTTP response to your request is. I attempted using the code below, but got a 504 - Connection Failed error.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var samNS = samNS || {};

        $(function () {
            alert ("dfdfad");
            samNS.sam = function ()
            {
                alert("entere");
                $.getJSON(
                    'https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json',
                    {
                        'auth-userid':'232323',
                        'auth-password':'xxxx',
                        'domain-name':'yyyy',
                        'tlds':'com',
                        'tlds':'info',
                        'suggest-alternative':'true'
                    },
                    function(json, textStatus, xhr) {
                        alert ("inside the fun");
                        alert("JSON Data: " + json);
                    }
                );

                alert("finish");
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
</div>
<button onclick="samNS.sam();">Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont think httpapi.com is a real domain nane :)

Comment: Hi geeks, as i mentioned in my earlier post, it need to register the ip address from which the requests could be sent.. Its working fine for me.. if you to want to check, pls give me your ip address , i'll add that in the settings and then you can get response..